# Slim Test Error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I am setting up a PHP Slim 3 boilerplate project and I am trying to set up an environment for which I can run my tests.

To do this, I created a set-up php class file that inherited the PHPUnit (v 7.5) test class, which my tests classes would inherit.

Here is what my test file looks like:

```
// Testcase.php
<?php

use Slim\App;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    protected $app;

    protected $withMiddleware = true;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->createApplication();
    }

    protected function createApplication()
    {
        $config = require_once __DIR__ . '/../config/index.php';

        $app = new App(['settings' => $config]);

        $dependencies = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/dependencies.php';
        $dependencies($app); // Line 26

        $routes = require_once __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php';
        $routes($app);

        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function request(string $request_method, string $request_uri = null, $request_data = null, array $headers = [])
    {
        // Functionality to prepare app to process request
    }
}
```

The `dependencies.php` file in the `bootstrap` folder looks something like this:

```
<?php

$config = require_once '../config/index.php';

$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => $config]);

$dependencies = require_once 'dependencies.php';
$dependencies($app);

$routes = require_once '../routes/web.php';
$routes($app);

return $app;
```

Anytime I try to run this: `./vendor/bin/phpunit --verbose`, I get the error:

> Error: Function name must be a string` on TestCase.php Line: 26

The same happens when I comment it out, leaving only the `$routes = require_once...` part; running a test throws same error on that line.

This same `dependencies.php` is what I use to access routes on my postman app and everything looks fine but not while running tests.

I don't know what is going on or what I am not doing properly. Is there any way I could go around this?

Comment: `$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => $config]);` does not make senses when $config is `= require_once` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @tim the ` require_once  __DIR__ . '/../config/index.php'` returns an array. So the if you do `var_dump($config)` after that line, you will get something equivalent to `$config = [... settings data ...]`

Comment: ok, as long as `$config` is defined in that file it's ok, but the` $config=` on that line actually does nothing as `requre_once` has no return value. looking at the slim docs, if `$config`  is in the right format you should just be using `$app = new \Slim\App($config);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is caused by `require_once` usage

you need to realize that during tests, this line with `require_once` is called more than once (presuming that you have more than one test scenario with `createApplication()` call because `phpunit setUp()` is called before each test)

when the `require_once` is called "again" it will return `"true"` instead of any value returned from required file ;)

have a look on following example:

```
<?php // inc.php
return 'foo';
```

and

```
<?php // test.php
$a = require_once 'inc.php';
$b = require_once 'inc.php';
var_dump($a, $b);
```

calling test.php will produce

```
string(3) "foo"
bool(true)
```

you need to use `require` instead of `require_once`

- also if you have some logic in files you will need probably to fix this (depends what the code does in required files)

Comment: Thank you so much @jDolba, this actually fixed the error.